# How to remove those characters in a string which are also present in an String array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I have a long list of Array strings (Like 500 +). I want to use this array as my character set and remove the occurrences of these substrings in my String array in the Main string.

```
NSArray *Arr = @["a1","a2","a3" ..........];

NSString *mainString = @"Stackoverflow is a1Right Placa2e toa3 ask a4 for Help";
```

`Expected Answer : StackOverflow is the best place to ask for help`

It is something like this and I have to remove a1, a2, a3 and a4 from my `Main String`.

I have checked some methods like `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and Defining `Character Array` but none of them actually helped me to understand how to implement in Objective C.

Comment: how about using [`replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1418451-replacecharactersinrange?language=objc)?

Comment: I have them in an array, so cannot use it may be.

Comment: what makes you think it cannot be used?

Comment: Maybe try looping through all the strings in the array…?

Comment: Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` with a for loop on `arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic way to do this is mentioned below.

```
    NSArray *Arr = @[@"a1",@"a2",@"a3",@"a4"];

    NSString *mainString = @"Stackoverflow is a1Right Placa2e toa3 ask a4 for Help";


    for (NSString* aValue in Arr) {

         mainString = [mainString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:aValue withString:@""];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", mainString);
```

Hope this helps.